Am really building a microservice system?
Thank you Erick, deleting this question

True microservices aim to encapsulate functionality such that each service can operate independently, or with minimal dependency, on others to avoid tight coupling.
This can be tough, but usually the following approaches can help (not all of them need to be applied at the same time, it depends on the complexities of your use case):

Event-Driven Architecture (via a message broker)
API Gateway or a BFF (Backend for Frontend)
Data Duplication (intentional denormalization)
Dedicated Junction Service (middleware service)

You already thought about the last, so yes, this can be an option. But while very personal opinion-based, I'd suggest that you don't go too far on micro-services if your use case isn't complex enough to justify the extra burden.
